# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Read-only field modified in setParameters()

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Here is my code

```
function createPeer(userID) {
    const peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
            {
                urls: "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org"
            },
            {
                urls: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
                credential: 'redacted',
                username: 'webrtc@live.com'
            },
        ]
    });
    peer.onicecandidate = () => { };
    peer.ontrack = () => { };
    peer.onnegotiationneeded = () => { };

    return peer;
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then(stream => {
    const peer = createPeer();
    peer.getSenders();
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, stream));
    peer.getSenders().forEach(sender => {
        if (sender.track.kind === "video") {
            const params = sender.getParameters();
            params.encodings.push({
                maxBitrate: 100
            });
            sender.setParameters(params);
        }
    })
});
```

I dont understand why I get the error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Read-only field modified in setParameters().

I thought bitrate was something I can change. Furthermore, I am changing the parameters I am getting by calling the `sender.getParameters();` which is what the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/setParameters) say to do.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: obligatory reminder: using muaz-khan's credentials for the viagenie turn server isn't going work, he changed them at least half a decade ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a new encoding to the array instead of modifying the existing encoding.  You need to wait until after negotiation is complete (you applied an answer), then do:

```
    peer.getSenders().forEach(sender => {
        if (sender.track.kind === 'video') {
            let params = sender.getParameters();
            params.encodings.forEach(e => {
                e.maxBitrate = 100;
            });
            sender.setParameters(params);
        }
    })
```

Comment: the problem is the array is empty, tho after researching this further, I think the array is empty because I have not established a remote connection yet. It seems that the encodings array only has a value once a connection is established

Comment: the encodings array will be empty before setLocalDescription so you'll need to modify when that code is called.